# select combo-box item is not working in edge browser selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, microsoft-edge

```
public static void select_Smart_ComboBox_WithCode(String object, String data) {
    WebElement ele = getLocatorObject(object); 
    ele.clear();
    ele.sendKeys(data + Keys.ARROW_RIGHT);
    String objID = ele.getAttribute(id);  
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(div[id= + objID.substring(0, objID.indexOf(_)) + ] div[id= + data + ] span[class=ffb-match])).click(); 
   }
```

We are using Selenium WebDriver and I have a method that will enter a value into a combo-box input and we will get dropdown options which we need to select the specific option
This code is working fine in Chrome however in Edge its failing sporadically.
Any thoughts or ideas will be a great help

Comment: I think the combo-box you mentioned refers to `input + datalist`, right? I tried using Microsoft Edge 103.0.1264.62 and Selenium 4.3 and I found it works fine. This is the [example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoX8R.png). If possible, can you provide more details, such as a simple example that reproduces the problem, and the environment in which the problem occurs (Edge version and Selenium version).

Comment: Yes, combo-box is input with data list. I am using 103.0.1264.49 edge version with selenium 3.6.0.  Its sporadic issue. One example is when you enter any data in the input text and if you have more then one option in the list then it fails most of the time edge compare to chrome which picks the first option. Let me get you some example